# database query table select starts at second row not first

Tags: php, html, mysql, smarty

Basically im using html, php, Smarty.

When i loop my results to display database table rows it ignores the first row of my database table.

So if i have a table with 3 rows (product_id = 1, product_id = 2, product_id = 3), it displays only product_id  '2' and '3'.

**I want to be able to display the first row - (product_id = 1)**

**.PHP**

```
<?php

$new = ['product_id','product_category','product_price','product_quantity','product_about','product_color'];

//Database connection
 $db = mysqli_connect('xxx','xxx','xxx','xxx')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//access Smarty template engine
require_once('Smarty-3.1.30/libs/Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->template_dir = 'views';
$smarty->compile_dir = 'tmp';


//query product page
$query = "SELECT * FROM cs_shop";
mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


//query an array of products
$rows = array();

 //loop start
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'product_id' => $row['product_id'],
        'product_category' => $row['product_category'],
        'product_price' => $row['product_price'],
        'product_quantity' => $row['product_quantity'],
        'product_about' => $row['product_about'],
        'product_color' => $row['product_color']
    );
}

//db collect data
$smarty->assign('row', $rows); 
//template
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

mysqli_close($db);

?>
```

**.TPL**

```
<div class="test divider">

<ul>
  {foreach from=$row item="item"}
  <li>{$item['product_id']}</li>
  {/foreach}
</ul>

</div>
```

**Results**

```
2
3
```

Now how to display the **missing id**.. im new to this so any tips or help of any kind is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Expected Result**

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the following line right after your query `$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);`:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); // REMOVE ME
```

It retrieves the first result, then you don't do anything with it before it enters your `while` loop and gets the next one.

Comment: Thanks!! So just to clear it up, it calls the first row, and the the while loop actually starts with the second row becuase the first one is called and never used?

Comment: Yep. Calling `mysqli_fetch_array()` retrieves a row. Each time you call it, it will retrieve the next one.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: Also you have 2 mysqli_query for same purpose. Please remove mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.'); add die() to the other query  if needed